# How to pass the username by using session function

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "testing";
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
if (isset($_POST['loginID'])) {
    $loginID = $_POST['loginID'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE loginID='".$loginID."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
        header("Location:homepage.php");
        $_SESSION['loginID'] = $loginID;
    } else {
        header("Location:login.php");die;
    }
}
?>
```

I want to pass the username in a session, to show the username in `homepage.php`, but it didn't work when I tried to do so. What is wrong, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Move this line - $_SESSION['loginID']=$loginID; - before you set your header.

Comment: Never, ever use unsanitized user input in a query.

Comment: Your code will never got setting Session value line; because you are redirecting to another page by `header("Location:homepage.php");`

Comment: Sorry inform that I make some mistake.. what I actually mean is,, I login my web using loginID (example-111111) and password(example-abcde). After login into my homepage. I want to retrieve the username(example-alex) from my database.

Comment: as a suggestion to your code : If you will use the query like you write and not use parametrized query you risk being hacked by sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res)==1)
{
header("Location:homepage.php");
$_SESSION['loginID']=$loginID;
}
```

to this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res)==1)
{
$_SESSION['loginID']=$loginID;
header("Location:homepage.php");
}
```

Comment: this is my homepage code.                                        <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
session_start();
echo "Welcome,".$_SESSION['name']."!";
?>                                                                    What i expect is "Welcome, alex!" but not "Welcome,12345!"

Comment: Clearly you've stored 12345 in $_SESSION['name']. That should be an easy error to track down.

Answer (score 0):

session value should be stored first and then redirect to another page. Try following:
    if(mysql_num_rows($res)==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['loginID']=$loginID;
        header("Location:homepage.php");
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch a row from your result set and use information from that row for your session variable:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $_SESSION['loginID'] = $loginID;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['username'];    // or whatever the column is called where the username is stored
    header("Location:homepage.php");
    exit();
} else {
    header("Location:login.php");die;
}
```

Apart from that a few comments:

- You should switch to PDO or mysqli using prepared statements. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you have an sql injection problem now;
- You should never store plain-text (or encrypted...) passwords. Passwords should be salted and hashed, see [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)